# Fastest way to check if a record exists in an Oracle Database with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to figure out if a key exists in an Oracle database using Entity Framework. My front end uses this call a lot, I was wondering which approach would be fastest? Should I get the first matching record and check if is null, check the count of the key and see if it's greater than one, or use Any? Or is there a solution I haven't thought of that is quicker than these?

Comment: If it is a key, why not use `context.Entity.Find(keyValue)`? It will also not call the database if the record is in the context.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend `Any`, as you don't need to count. It should be translated to an EXISTS statement, which is faster than a COUNT(*).

Maybe something like:

```
var exists = ctx.MyEntities.Where(x => x.Id == ...).Any();
```

Don't instantiate your entity (e.g., using `Find`) because that would hurt the performance, as you only want to check if a record exists.